# How to query which node executed a step? How to schedule a step on the same node as a previous step?

Tags: argo-workflows

I have 3 argo workflow steps that I want to schedule always on the same node. Is it possible to limit execution of the 2nd and 3rd steps to the node that executed the 1st step? How can I get the executing node name/label during executing the step? Is this possible? My idea is I could put it into an output variable, then use that with a nodeSelector in the subsequent steps.

What I have currently is that all 3 steps are always scheduled on one designated node using :

```
spec:
  templates:
    - name: first-step
      nodeSelector:
        mycustomlabel: "true"
```

But the issue is this creates a CPU and disk space bottleneck.